# Operação com endereço de memória em c

Tags: c, memória, bits

estou estudando sobre o acesso aos endereços de variáveis em c, buscando exemplos práticos utilizando ponteiros. Em um dos exemplos declarei uma variável:

```
int var = 15;
```

utilizei um ponteiro "point1" que apontasse para o endereço dessa variável:

```
point1 = &var;
```

e utilizei outro ponteiro "point2" para receber o valor de uma operação realizada diretamente com o endeço da memória:

```
point2 = &point1 + 0;
```

O endereço apontado pelo programa para a variável "var" e pelo ponteiro "point1" foi o 62fe14, porém o endereço de "point2" foi 62fe08, porque isto ocorreu? Ao somar um valor zero ao endereço da variável, não deveria ter sido atribuido o mesmo endereço de point1 para point2?

---

Código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    
    int var;
    int* point1;
    int** point2;
    
    var = 15;
    
    printf("valor de var: %d\n", var);
    
    point1 = &var;
    
    printf("\nposicao na memoria: %x\n", point1);   //sem o operarador * o point é uma variável que recebe o valor da memória
    
    point2 = &point1 + 0;
    
    printf("\nverifica novamente posicao na memoria: %x\n", point1);
    printf("\nNovo endereço point2: %x\n", point2);
    printf("\nvalor de 0: %x", 0);  //teste para verificar valor utilizando na operação de bits
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: e como declarou os ponteiros `point1` e `point2`? coloque o código completo

Comment: são endereços de memória diferentes, já tentou fazer simplesmente `point2 = &point1` e ver o resultado? é o mesmo, pq point1 aponta pro endereço de memória de var, e point2 por sua vez aponta para o endereço de memória de point1

Comment: Quando vc soma um número `n` a um ponteiro, está somando n vezes o tamanho do tipo do ponteiro. Por exemplo, se o ponteiro for `int *p` então `p + n` pega o endereço para o qual `p` aponta e soma `n * sizeof(int)`

Comment: Ficou claro agora, obrigado pelas respostas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O operador `&` em C serve para retornar o endereço de memória de uma variável. Os apontadores são variáveis que armazenam endereço de memória de outras variáveis, contudo os apontadores possuem seus próprios endereços de memória também.

Quando você faz a atribuição:

```
point2 = &point1 + 0;
```

Você está atribuindo em `point2` o valor do endereço de `point1` e **não** o valor do endereço de `var` que está armazenado em `point1`.

Sendo assim, a variável `point2` está armazenando o endereço de memória de `point1`, `point1` por sua vez, também é um apontador, dessa forma você consegue fazer alterações na variável `var` através de `point1` utilizando o operador `*` e também consegue fazer alteração na variável `var` com a variável `point2` utilizando o operador `**`.

Note que se você utilizar o operador `*` com a variável `point2` em vez de `**`, você estará alterando o valor de `point1` que está armazenando o endereço de memória de `var` e não estará alterando o valor de `var`.

Para elucidar, alterei o código da seguinte forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    
    int var;
    int* point1;
    int** point2;
    
    var = 15;
    
    printf("Valor de var: %d\n", var);
    
    point1 = &var;
    printf("Valor de point1 (endereco de memoria de var): %x\n", point1);
    
    point2 = &point1;
    printf("Valor de point2 (endereco de memoria de point1): %x\n", point2);
    printf("Valor de point1 (acessando valor de point1 a partir de point2): %x\n\n", *point2);
    
    //Alterando o valor de var com point1
    *point1 = 20;
    printf("Valor de var (alterado utilizando point1): %d\n", var);
    
    //Alterando o valor de var com point2
    **point2 = 25;
    printf("Valor de var (alterado utilizando point2): %d\n", var);
    
    getch();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Ponteiros de ponteiros são mais utilizados quando temos que passar um ponteiro como parâmetro "por referência" de uma função, isto é, precisamos alterar o valor da variável ponteiro que foi passada por parâmetro para uma função.

Recomendo leitura:
http://linguagemc.com.br/ponteiros-em-c/

Comment: "Você está atribuindo em point2 o valor do endereço de point1 e não o valor do endereço de var que está armazenado em point1." Em relação a esse trecho, e se eu quiser atribuir em point2 o endereço de var através de point1, teria como?

Comment: @douglas Tem sim, basta fazer  `int  *point2 = point1`. Pois `point1` é um ponteiro que aponta para `var`, então basta atribui-lo a outro ponteiro para que ambos apontem para o mesmo endereço

Comment: @hkotsubo deu certo. Obrigado a todos que responderam.